# TYPO3 - Configure tx_news to use the style og Bootstrap Package CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typo3, tx-news

How can I make tx_news use the pagination styles from the Bootstrap Package?

Comment: What did you try so far to achieve it? Did you copy the PaginationWidget template etc.? Please give some more information where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I haven't done anything. I do not know where to start. I can find the PaginationWidget in tx_news, but what do I do with it to adapt the Bootstrap CSS?

Answer (score 1):

In your TS add config

```
plugin.tx_news {
    widget.GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = EXT:YOURPATH/Resources/Private/Templates/Ext/tx_news/Templates/
    }
```

and add there

> YOURPATH/Resources/Private/Templates/Ext/tx_news/Templates/ViewHelpers/Widget/Paginate/Index.html

then some code

```
{namespace n=GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers}


    <f:renderChildren arguments="{contentArguments}" />


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <f:render section="paginator" arguments="{pagination: pagination, configuration:configuration, class:'pagination-lg'}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
            <f:render section="paginator" arguments="{pagination: pagination, configuration:configuration, class:'pagination-sm'}" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 visible-sm">
            <f:render section="paginator" arguments="{pagination: pagination, configuration:configuration, class:'pagination-lg'}" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <f:section name="paginator">
        <f:if condition="{pagination.numberOfPages} > 1">
            <f:if condition="{settings.list.paginate}">
                <f:if condition="{pagination.current} > 1">
                    <n:headerData><link rel="prev" href="<f:widget.uri arguments="{currentPage: pagination.previousPage}" />" /></n:headerData>
                </f:if>
                <f:if condition="{pagination.nextPage}">
                    <n:headerData><link rel="next" href="<f:widget.uri arguments="{currentPage: pagination.nextPage}" />" /></n:headerData>
                </f:if>  
            </f:if>

            <ul class="pagination {class}">
                <f:if condition="{pagination.previousPage}">
                    <f:then>
                        <li class="previous">
                            <f:if condition="{pagination.previousPage} > 1">
                                <f:then>
                                    <f:widget.link arguments="{currentPage: pagination.previousPage}">&#8592;</f:widget.link>
                                </f:then>
                                <f:else>
                                    <f:widget.link>&#8592;</f:widget.link>
                                </f:else>
                            </f:if>
                        </li>
                    </f:then> 
                    <f:else>
                        <li class="disabled">
                            <a href="#">&#8592;</a>
                        </li>
                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
                <f:for each="{pagination.pages}" as="page">
                    <f:if condition="{page.isCurrent}">
                        <f:then>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">{page.number}</a></li>
                        </f:then>
                        <f:else>
                            <li>
                                <f:if condition="{page.number} > 1">
                                    <f:then>
                                        <f:widget.link arguments="{currentPage: page.number}">{page.number}</f:widget.link>
                                    </f:then>
                                    <f:else>
                                        <f:widget.link>{page.number}</f:widget.link>
                                    </f:else>
                                </f:if>
                            </li>
                        </f:else>
                    </f:if>
                </f:for>
                <f:if condition="{pagination.nextPage}">
                    <li class="last next">
                        <f:widget.link arguments="{currentPage: pagination.nextPage}">&#8594;</f:widget.link>
                    </li>
                </f:if>
            </ul>
        </f:if>
    </f:section>
```

Pls dont forget edit your folder path